# MikTeX 2.9 does not respond under Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

Tags: miktex

Two weeks ago I installed MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit on my laptop with OS Windows 10 Pro 64 bit. When working a while on a document (article) MiKTeX all of a sudden no longer responds. This invariably happens when I activate a menu option (for example to compile or to enlarge the pdf compilation) or simply when moving the mouse across the menu bar. The program seems to 'hang' itself. Both screens, code and pdf (I use the option pdfLaTeX when compiling), are visible and can be clicked down to the taskbar, but that's it. Closing the program, saving the work, using menu options and working in the document is no longer possible. No error or warning messages appear.
The only option left is closing the program using the task manager, and then start it up again. But after a while the problem reoccurs.
What goes wrong here? The installation went fine. I tried, but to no avail:
- uninstall MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit and install MiKTeX 2.9 32 bit;
- updating MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit and 32 bit;
- running or not running other programs at the same time as MiKTeX 2.9.
I previously worked with MiKTeX 2.9 32 bit on a desktop with Windows Vista Ultimate 32 bit and experienced no problems.
Does someone have an idea?

Cor Vermeulen
The Netherlands

Comment: With "working on a document" I mean that I'm typing text, formula's etc. in the code section of MiKTeX. Every few lines I compile it to see if it looks good. After a while the program 'freezes'. No warnings or error messages pop up. After closing down the program with the task manager, I start the program up again. Then everything is normal. I open the document again and I go on entering text, formulas etc. Then the problem reoccurs. The program simply no longer responds. I'm not an experienced user yet. I hope I made clear just what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry. I  really don't understand your comment. I'm not using an editor. I'm just using MiKTeX, the program itself. There I type what I mean. Then I compile it in a pdf file. In other words: I open TeXworks and create a new or I open an existing LaTeX file.

Comment: Okay! TeXworks compiles fine. I checked the log file of the HelloWorld file. It contains a lot of information about the file I created, but, as far as I can see, no errors or warnings. The program compiles well, but every 15 minutes or so the program 'freezes'. And not just when I want to compile. I move my mouse across the menu bar, for example, and the program simply no longer responds.

Comment: Sounds as if texworks has a problem. Install and try out some other editor, e.g. texstudio.

Comment: The only thing that looks like an error message in the log file is: No file "Hello World!".aux.
\openout1 = `"Hello World!.aux"'. But when I check the folder I use, there is an .aux file in it with the same name (HelloWorld!).

Comment: I installed Texstudio. But the same problem occurs. When I click 'edit' in the menu, for example, the program freezes. No longer any response.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that your installation of MiKTeX has problems.  I do not use Windows 10, but I had an similar problem with Windows 8.1.

I got from time to time error messaged from windows 8 that an application crash happend.  Please check your system panel for error messages and report them to the MiKTeX support.

At last I got rid of this problem by doing the following things:

1. uninstall MiKTeX and editors
2. **Reboot** windows
3. I forced an update of windows
4. **Reboot** windows
5. Download the **current** installer for complete MiKTeX
6. Install MiKTeX.  Please make sure, that the installation is **complete**. It could happen, that the downloading and installing of MiKTeX can be interrupted by an unreachable download server (one student of mine had to restart the MikTeX installer for 11 times!).
7. **Reboot** windows
8. Run the package manager of MiKTeX (you have to do that, the installer does not always install the current versions of packages. The package manager checks that and show you all packages with newer versions available.
9. **Reboot** windows. Check if you got unusual windows errors with the system panal.
10. Test MiKTeX with commandline and compile your `HelloWorld.tex` with `pdflatex HelloWorld.tex`. Check the `log` file for errors or warnings. There should be none of them.
11. Download the installer for your prefered editor and install it.  Check that the installation is complete.  If you need to configure the editor do it.
12. **Reboot** windows to make sure the new program can work properly.
13. Test your editor compiling `HelloWorld.tex`. Check the `log` file again. There should be no warnings or error messages.

I ask you to do the reboots to be sure windows had finished the installing and updating MiKTeX.  All my students following this advice have no problems running MiKTeX.

It seems that windows needs the reboots to be able to finish the installation process.  If you omit the reboot it **can be** that the installing is not finished and that results in variing error situations.

Comment: Short summary: {reboot windows}\loop.

Comment: That was supposed to be funny.  I am well familiar with the problems you addressed in your answer.

Comment: Absolutely plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the existing MiKTeX from your system and download the latest MiKTeX 'basic miktex-2.9.5872 64 bit and install the same in your system. After installation open the texworks editor (coming along with miktex) and navigate to edit >> preference. A popup will come. In that go to typesetting and check that if the path is correctly set.Then in text editor create one file called first.tex  with the code \documentclass{article}\begin{document} Hello world to \LaTeX \end{document}and then compile with pdflatex command. It will work.